# Reference to the theorem about integer labeling on bipartite graph vertices

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request

I need a reference for the following easy theorem. Of course, I can prove it myself, but maybe there is any book with a proof? (i'm not familiar with the literature in graph theory)

Suppose a bipartite graph, whose vertices $v_i$ are labeled by integers $a_i$, is given. For every edge we can add the same integer to its ends. Then we can get the zero labeling using this operations iff the sums of $a_i$ in both parts are equal.

I do not need a proof, just a reference.

Comment: What does it mean to "apply" an integer to the ends of an edge?

Comment: @MishaLavrov thank you, "add" was meant.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to begin with, your easy theorem is false: it leaves out the word "connected"...

In general, this is a network flow type of result. It's not a *standard* network flow type of result, so I don't know a citation that tells it to you directly, but you can at least outsource the annoying parts of the proof to the [max-flow min-cut theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Max-flow_min-cut_theorem) by defining a network appropriately.

(For example, for each vertex on the left with label $x > 0$ and for each vertex on the right with label $x<0$, add an edge from the source to that vertex with capacity $|x|$. For each vertex on the left with label $y < 0$ and for each vertex on the right with label $y>0$, add an edge from that vertex to the sink with capacity $|y|$. All original edges of the graph should be undirected and have infinite capacity.)

It's possible that you can find a specialized network flow problem equivalent to this one. For example, "the sums of labels on both sides are equal" is a well-known condition for feasibility in the [transportation problem](https://www.me.utexas.edu/~jensen/models/network/net8.html). But your problem differs from that one in a few ways:

- It's a restricted transportation problem: your graph is not the complete bipartite graph.
- You allow negative numbers to be added to edges, equivalent to a negative flow along that edge. Equivalently, we want an undirected version of the transportation problem.

But I don't have a citation for you of anyone considering an undirected restricted transportation problem.